# Summing over a N dimensional function - Monte Carlo Integration?

Tags: java, numerical-methods, montecarlo

I wanted to evaluate a certain sum needed for a monte carlo method in N dimensions. In N dimensions I have N variables with M data points, meaning that I basically have M N-D vectors representing M sampling points. I have to hold one variable fixed while I sum over all other variables for M values. Currently my code is (assuming my mesh which has N columns and M rows is static):

```
 public static double myFunction(int row, int col){
      double checkMesh = mesh[row][col]; 
      return myFunctionHelper(0,col,checkMesh); 
 }

 public static double myFunctionHelper(int j, int col, double checkMesh){
      //function is initialized with j=0 
      if (j >= mesh[0].length){
           return 0;
      }
      double sum = 0;
      for (int i=0 ; i<mesh.length ; i++){
           sum += myFunctionHelper(j+1,col,checkMesh);
           if (j==mesh[0].length-1){
                if (mesh[0][col]==checkMesh){
                     sum += function(mesh[0]);
                }
                mesh = rotate(mesh,j);
           }
      }
      if (j>=1){
           mesh = rotate(mesh,j-1);
      }
      return sum;
 }
```

Now this function works but it doesn't hold any variables fixed, instead it just sums over all possible combinations of variables. I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how I can alter this to make it work as I want it to. Currently the only workaround that I can think of is to remove the fixed column from my matrix, sum over the combinations of the altered matrix, and when the function gets evaluated make sure the fixed variable is included in the right spot of an altered list, except I want to avoid doing this as it requires more memory and isn't as clean. I'd appreciate the help :).

EDIT: The rotate function takes the mesh and rotates the j-th column by one vertically upwards movement. Also function takes a vector as an argument, where the vector is represented by an array.

Comment: It is not very clear what you mean by "hold one variable fixed". Please rework your question to make clear what are the givens, and what you want to compute. Provide a numeric example with, say, N=2 and M=3.

Comment: Why are you using recursion? Could you make the intention of your code clearer by refactoring it without recursion?

Comment: @JoachimWuttke The code is for evaluating a sum. Suppose you get M vectors in R^{3} and you want to evaluate f(x_{i},y_{i},z_{i}). This function holds a single element of the specified i-th vector fixed (suppose its x_{2}) as you sum over the other variables. If M =3 this function would then evaluate the sum: f(x_{2},y_{1},z_{1})+f(x_{2},y_{1},z_{2})+f(x_{2},y_{1},z_{3})+f(x_{2},y_{2},z_{1})+f(x_{2},y_{2},z_{2})+f(x_{2},y_{2},z_{3})+f(x_{2},y_{3},z_{1})+f(x_{2},y_{3},z_{2})+f(x_{2},y_{3},z_{3}). The code above was modified but the overall idea works.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke I updated my function to show what I have now.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You are computing the sum recursively, through myFunctionHelper calling myFunctionHelper. This may work, but it makes the code more involved than necessary. Recursion is not really not suited for this kind of numeric computation. Rewrite your algorithm without recursion, as a double loop over row and columnd indices, and things will get much clearer.

(2) With `mesh[0][col]==checkMesh` you try to identify the fixed entry **by value**. Why not **by** column and row **index**?